# How to create a multi-process webkitgtk application (Vala)?

Tags: webkit, vala

I want to make a web browser in Vala using webkit.

But, I don't know how to make it multi-process.

I want each tab to have its own process.

How can I do that using Vala and Gtk+.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`Gtk.Plug`](http://valadoc.org/gtk+-2.0/Gtk.Plug.html) and [`Gtk.Socket`](http://valadoc.org/gtk+-2.0/Gtk.Socket.html). You'll need to put a `Gtk.Socket` in each tab you open. Then spawn a process using one of the [`GLib.Process`](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Process.html) functions, and in that process construct a `Gtk.Plug` containing your `WebView`. Then you'll need some way of inter-process communication, for one thing to connect your plug to your socket, and to pass commands from your user-interface to the webview (such as "make the font larger").

It looks like the Vala documentation doesn't contain very much explanation, you might want to check out the [C documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/) for more information on how plugs and sockets work.

**EDIT:**

You asked for more information on inter-process communication. There are several ways, and I'm not sure which one is the most appropriate for you. Perhaps you can try `GLib.Process.spawn_async_with_pipes()` to start your child process and get file descriptors for the child's standard input and output. You can then pass these file descriptors to [`GLib.IOChannel.unix_new()`](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.IOChannel.html) to pass messages back and forth between your processes.

Another way is to use DBus, but that's more complicated and less documented.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.

I don't know how to use Glib.Process.

I follow a tutoriel about Plugs and Sockets (gtkmm book - http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-plugs-sockets-example.html.en), but the way of transmitting the window ID is not very appropriate (in a file).

So, how can I communicate between two processes using Glib.Process ?
I did that to launch the other process (C++) :
list<string> myList;
myList.push_back("../Plug/Plug");
Glib::spawn_async(".", myList);
which launch the process but, I want to communicate between them.

How ?
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [GtkPlug](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkPlug.html) see this [discussion in Vala-list](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/vala-list/2010-March/msg00017.html) (and [gtk forum](http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?p=14627)).